# Remove records from dataframe that exist in another column but keeping some based on a specific priority with python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to plot on a map those names that do not have already a neighbour, so I need to remove from my dataframe all names that already have a known neighbour preserving those with the highest age.

```
df=pd.DataFrame(
list(zip(
['Isabel Garcia','Isabel Garcia','Raul Jimenez','Laura Gomez','Laura Gomez','Maria 
Garcia','Paco Garcia','Isa Gomez','Lucas Gomez','Roberto Sanchez'],
[65,65,55,50,50,45,44,30,25,40],
['Maria Garcia','Paco Garcia','','Isa Gomez','Lucas Gomez','Isabel Garcia','Isabel 
Garcia','Laura Gomez','Laura Gomez','']
)),
columns=['Name','Age','Neighbour'])
df
```

[image]

I want to get this as my final result:

```
pd.DataFrame(['Isabel Garcia','Raul Jimenez','Laura Gomez','Roberto Sanchez'], columns 
['Name'])
```

[image]

I already tried to loop over the dataframe trying to append to a list all neighbours excluding those already looped over and want to preserve but all things I tried end up removing all values.

```
lsss=[]
lsss1=[]


for idx, row in df[~df['Name'].isin(lsss2)].iterrows():
   lsss.append(row['Name'])#names looped over
   #list of neighbours of those looped over
   lsss1.append(df[df['Name']==row['Name']]['Neighbour'])
   #flatten list and keep unique values
   flat_list = list(dict.fromkeys([item for sublist in lsss1 for item in sublist]))
   lsss2=flat_list#copy list of neighbours
   for e in lsss:#remove from list those to keep
      try:
        lsss2.remove(e)
      except ValueError:
        pass

   df[~df['Name'].isin(lsss2)]
```

Comment: I don't get your desired output df with the 4 names. Raul and Roberto don't have a neighbour, but Isabel (->Maria) and Laura (->Isa and Lucas) have neighbours. Is there another criteria you didn't mention? Maybe that last name has to be different to be a valid neighbour ?

Comment: Hi, maybe I can explain it in this way: From the initial list of names Maria Garcia and Paco Garcia should be removed because they have Isabel Garcia as neighbour. Isa Gomez and Lucas Gomez should be removed because they have Laura Gomez as neighbour.

Comment: so the order of the list of names top bottom is important. valid neighbour is only a name who already appeared in the `name` column, right ?

Comment: Yes and I already sorted the names in order of age, so when two persons are neighbours I keep the one with the highest age.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is satisfying for you but here is a way to get your expected output.

```
known = set()
remaining_ppl = set(df['Name'])
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    known.add(row['Name'])
    if row['Neighbour'] in known:
        remaining_ppl.discard(row['Name'])

print(remaining_ppl) #because remaining_ppl is a set, it is not ordered

Output:
{'Raul Jimenez', 'Isabel Garcia', 'Roberto Sanchez', 'Laura Gomez'}
```

If you want to have the filtered df you could do:

```
df.loc[df['Name'].isin(remaining_ppl), :]

Output:
    Name            Age Neighbour
0   Isabel Garcia   65  Maria Garcia
1   Isabel Garcia   65  Paco Garcia
2   Raul Jimenez    55  
3   Laura Gomez     50  Isa Gomez
4   Laura Gomez     50  Lucas Gomez
9   Roberto Sanchez 40
```

Comment: Yes, that works fine and gives me the desired output. However my real dataframe has thousands of rows and I am trying also to avoid looping over rows that I already know should be excluded. For example I could avoid iterating over Maria Garcia because she is neighbour of Isabel Garcia. Any idea? Anyway thanks for your answer because it returned the desired output and I can work with that!

Comment: I get what you want, I tried, but tbh I don't know how it should be done. Same for the looping over the rows. Since the order matters I'm not sure how to solve it without looping. Maybe someone else can help here.

Comment: is your goal a filtered df like I showed you in my answer ?